# Scale values in [-1, 1] range with D3's scale function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bunch of values that are to be plotted on a chart. The sample data is as below:

```
[0, 0, -0.015, 0, 0.12, -0.654, 0, 0, 0.0029, 0.879, -1.54, 0, 0, ...]
```

As you can see, most of the data is (around) zero, but some of the values have a stronger deviation (outliers). I want to plot the data so the outliers can be decently distinct from the rest.

To do that, I have instantiated a scale with domain from -1 to 1:

```
var data = [...];
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([-1, 1]).range(d3.extent(data));
var dataScaled = data.map(function (d) {
    return yScale.invert(+d);
});
```

So when I pass e.g. `[-0.9, 0, 0.9]`, the scaled data will be `[-1, 0, 1]` just as expected.

The problem with this approach is, the data `[0, -0.9]` will be scaled to about `[-0.95, 0.95]`. I want it to scale to `[0, -1]`. Kind of scaling in a polar coord system with center in 0 and radius 1. Is this possible with d3 with an acceptable overhead?

A quick-and-dirty solution could be to have two scales, one for the positives and one for the negatives:

```
var yScalePos = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range(d3.extent(data.filter(function (d) {
            return d > 0;
        })));
    var yScaleNeg = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, 0])
        .range(d3.extent(v.root.children.filter(function (d) {
            return d < 0;
        })));
    var dataScaled = data.map(function (d) {
        if (d > 0)
            return yScalePos.invert(d);
        else if (d < 0)
            return yScaleNeg.invert(d);
        else
            return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is the best.

When you are doing `d3.scale.linear().domain([-1, 1]).range(d3.extent(data));` with your data being `var data = [0, -.9];`, you are basically telling d3 to put your maximum value at 1, and your minimum at -1.

The purpose of d3 linear scale is just to map a *range* to a *domain*, so even with data likes `var data = [0, .01]` you will get back `[-1, 1]`